# Angular error 'ContactController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ContactController" >

</div>
```

Above is my html file and This is controller file.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, ContactService,$window) {

    });
```

This is my html  section to have look. Please let me know if any mistake

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/controller/contactController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/service/contactService.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //var module = angular.module('app', [ContactService]);


    </script>
</head>
```

**I am getting error as  Argument 'ContactController' is not a function,got undefined**. Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: do u import `ContactService` js file?

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with other parts of your html. Could u provide  the whole html file?

Comment: Yes i import ContactService

Comment: Updating my html <head> in question

Comment: please import `contact.service.js` before controller

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the `()` in the first line.

Comment: means exactly where ?

Answer (score 0):

Try change order of import js file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" 
   </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/service/contact.service.js">   </script>type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/controller/contact.controller.js">
```

Comment: it worked after changing import sequence.. But i also had to declare var app = angular.module('app', []); This in service instead of controller. Why this is so ?

Comment: you can't inject `service` in your app. you can inject just  `module`